# wp_list_categories not working on my live site

Tags: categories

I am using `wp_list_categories` function it work on local server fine but on the live site its not working the code i am using for this is

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Categories 
                    </a>
                        <?php $args = array(
                            'show_option_all'    => '',
                            'orderby'            => 'name',
                            'order'              => 'ASC',
                            'style'              => 'list',
                            'show_count'         => 0,
                            'hide_empty'         => 1,
                            'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
                            'child_of'           => 0,
                            'feed'               => '',
                            'feed_type'          => '',
                            'feed_image'         => '',
                            'exclude'            => '1',
                            'exclude_tree'       => '',
                            'include'            => '',
                            'hierarchical'       => 1,
                            'title_li'           => '',
                            'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
                            'number'             => null,
                            'echo'               => 1,
                            'depth'              => 0,
                            'current_category'   => 0,
                            'pad_counts'         => 0,
                            'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                            'walker'             => null
                        ); ?>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu cat_drop">
                         <?php wp_list_categories($args); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

So any idea where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried, what were the results? Do you have posts with categories assigned? Have you tried without passing in all those unnecessary args? More info please.

Comment: yes i try just simple query without any `args` but it still not working. It show no `categories`